# Higher homotopy of knot theory space

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, knot-theory

Knot theory is the study of the path components of $\operatorname{Emb}(S^1 , \mathbb{R}^3)$. I know sometimes in geometric topology, these function spaces have very complicated path components, but relatively simple higher homotopy. Are the homotopy types of the path components of any particular knots known? And more generally, do we know the higher homotopy groups of $\operatorname{Emb}(S^1 , \mathbb{R}^n)$?

I imagine this is probably approached through embedding calculus, so I offer a meagre first step: if $n>3$ the codimension of the spaces is enough that the embedding tower converges. Moreover, it is well known that the first stage of the embedding tower is immersions, which in our case is equivalent to formal immersions. If I am not mistaken, this space $\operatorname{fimm}(S^1, \mathbb{R}^n)$ is equivalent to $\Omega_{free} S^{n-1}$ because both $S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are parallelizable and the latter contractible.

Could anyone outline the known work or provide references?

Comment: Yeah I’d also be interested in for example exhibiting a nontrivial element in pi_1

Comment: @AndresMejia I think the simplest example would just be if you think of the torus as a bunch of copies of the unknot fibered over $S^1$.

Comment: I've wondered about this in the past.  It seems plausible that the connect sum of $n$ copies of the trefoil has an embedding space with a nontrivial braid group action.  I think Ryan Budney might be interested in these sorts of things (and you might ask this question on mathoverflow, where he is likely to see it).  Another thing to possibly look into is how Vassiliev invariants (as Vassiliev did them) are from the 0th cohomology of this space, so maybe there is something to be said about 1st cohomology, too, through his techniques.

Comment: I was also going to suggest Budney. He computes the first homotopy group of $Emb(S^j,\mathbb{R}^m)$ for high codimension ($\geq3$, sorry) in Th. 3.9 of [A family of embedding spaces](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605069.pdf). He also has a paper [Topology of knot spaces in dimension 3](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0506524) which seems to focus on the space of long knots (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) but might have something in.

Comment: He cites Scannell-Sinha's paper [A one-dimensional embedding complex](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404901000780) which computes some rational homotopy groups of the space of long knots. tbh I don't think anything is known in dimension $3$ for standard embedding spaces $Emb(S^1,S^3)$.

Comment: @Tyrone Knudsen and Kupers have a pretty cool paper where they show for a simply connected, compact 4-manifold. The homotopy type of these embedding spaces doesn't depend on the smooth structure chosen. It's called "Embedding Calculus and Smooth Structures".

Comment: @KyleMiller You might be interested in this result as well.

Comment: Thanks! I was aware of Arone-Szymik's *Spaces of knotted circles and exotic smooth structures* from last year but I hadn't seen Kupers's paper. I spoke to Szymik at some point and he was quite excited about it all. It was a bit disappointing that the final results were mainly negative. It seems like Kupers's paper continues that trend... although I do plan to sit down sometime and look at the section about exotic spheres...

Comment: @Tyrone From what I understand of the paper, it seems to me that this result really should be confined to dimension 4 because in other dimensions the "formal smooth manifold" associated to different smooth structures should be different. However, the authors did seem very pessimistic about embedding calculus having applications to the 4d Poincare conjecture for this reason.

Comment: The Poincaré conjecture is what had us all interested in it in the first place. That's what I mean by exotic spheres! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Tyrone: Plenty is known about the case you suggest. The space of long knots just removes some ambiguity.

Remember that there is a fiber sequence $\text{Emb}_*(S^1, S^3) \to \text{Emb}(S^1, S^3) \to (TS^3 \setminus 0)$, the last map sending $\gamma$ to $\gamma'(0)$ and the first is the space of embeddings with prescribed values for $\gamma(0)$ and the derivative there.

The first space is seen to be equivalent to the space of long knots in $\Bbb R^3$ by a standard fiber sequence relating the space of embeddings with specified first derivative to the space of embeddings with specified germ. So a full understanding of the space of long knots gives rise to a full understanding of the space of all knots. The former is more natural and easier to compute in terms of.

To my recollection Budney has completely finished these calculations (perhaps in the paper you cite).

Comment: Is your statement about long knots being equivalent to pointed embeddings only for this case of 1 dimensional embedding inside 3 dimensional, or is it a general observation that holds for general dimensions? I ask because section 5.7 in this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.08146.pdf) by Fresse, Turchin, and Willwacher seems to suggest it is nontrivial to compare the general case.